# Make the second Textview in a TableRow scrollable if the text is too long

Tags: android, scroll, tablerow

i have a table layout like the hello, tablelayout on android dev -wow the site is down today -.-  . There are 2 textviews in 1 tableRow, the 1 should be at the left site.

The second should be fixed at the right side. But i have 2 textviews who are longer than the screen. If i start the application, i only see the middle /end of the long textviews, the short are right behind the screen. How can i make the short textviews fixed at the left screen side ?

I hope you know what i mean, my english is very bad but i think the content of my question is clear.

This is only the first part^^ the xml file is much longer 
    Here is the xml file :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>




<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:overScrollMode="always"
            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
            android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" >


                    <TableLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:stretchColumns="1">


                        <TableRow
                                    android:id="@+id/tableRow0"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >




                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_column="1"
                                        android:padding="3dip"
                                        android:textSize="20dp"
                                        android:text="@string/tab1_text1" 
                                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                        />


                             </TableRow>       


                        <View
                            android:layout_height="2dip"
                            android:background="#FF909090" />

                                <TableRow
                                    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >




                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_column="1"
                                        android:padding="3dip"
                                        android:text="@string/TV_1_1" android:textColor="#ffffff"/>



                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/in1_1"
                                        android:gravity="right"
                                        android:padding="3dip"
                                        android:text="TEXT2" android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

                                </TableRow>


                                <TableRow
                                    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >



                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_column="1"
                                        android:padding="3dip"
                                        android:text="@string/TV_1_2" android:textColor="#ffffff"/>




                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/in1_2"
                                        android:gravity="right"
                                        android:padding="3dip"
                                        android:text="TEXT2" android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

                                </TableRow>

                                <TableRow
                                    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >




                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_column="1"
                                        android:padding="3dip"
                                        android:text="@string/TV_1_3" android:textColor="#ffffff"/>


                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/in1_3"
                                        android:gravity="right"
                                        android:padding="3dip"
                                        android:text="TEXT2" 
                                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                                    android:singleLine="true" 
                                        android:ellipsize="marquee"
                                        android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
                                        android:focusable="true"
                                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
                                        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    />

                                </TableRow>
```

Comment: Maybe you could try make a visual representation by making a simple drawing in a paint tool. It is a bit vague what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Try encapsulating your TextViews inside their own ScrollViews, so in the event the TextView exceeds your pre-determined bounds, the ScrollView will take effect and you'll be able to scroll through the text.

Comment: http://file2.npage.de/011669/04/bilder/android_problemm_grafik_1.png


this sucks, please help me. thx

PS: sry i'm a new user, i cant post images. I hope the link is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Since you ignored my comment that would solve your problem...

```
<ScrollView>
    <TextView /> <--- The one with really long text
</ScrollView>
```

As I said in the comment, encapsulate the TextView that has the enormous text in it with a ScrollView object, and position the ScrollView in the same way you positioned the Textview, and you will solve your problem.

Comment: And the problem of a `ScrollView` inside a `ScrollView` how do you solve it?

Comment: i'm not a total newby xD i tried the scrollview around the textview, but i get at first the error : line ... , insert layout_width. then i get the error : insert layout_height. THEN i get a unspecific error without description.

Answer (score 0):

Your question was a bit difficult to understand, but looking at your illustration in the comments, i think you need to weight your TextViews. Take a look at the example below.

Note: this will not stretch your left column, as you had indicated in your TableLayout sample code.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="Hello layout_weight" />

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:text="Row 1, Col 1" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="Some long text in your left column, taking half the screen width"
        />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="This is the long scrolling text in your right column."
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: THATS the answer. I love you. Thx xD

Comment: But theres still a small problem. The Textviews with the long text dont scroll . They are freeze . Its Api 10, is this the problem ?

Comment: EDIT: Sometimes its work in the emulator, but if i scroll vertical, the automatic scroll runs not perfect, it stops for 1 second or doesnt work until i restart the application. But its not my computer ^^